# Review of "Low Quality Posts" when out of close votes

Tags: discussion, flags, review

The [Low Quality Posts review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/) shows low quality questions and answers.

When out of close votes I'm not sure what to do with the *questions*. I can still handle the answers fine as there are no limits on the actions I can take.

But for questions one of the actions (close) requires close votes. Sure, I say `ok` or `skip` but without the ability to vote for close the process feels a little pointless as I don't have a tool to say "this is bad" anymore and I'm "wasting" time skipping bad things.

Also I'm not sure how the "`not sure`" votes are recorded and if that degrades the quality of some collected stats when I repeated skip questions that are clearly bad.

One suggestion might be to not show low quality ***questions*** to people that are out of close votes.

---

*Some days later:* Now that the initial batch of "low quality posts" are done this might not be that big of an issue any more. Even so it happened to me again that I was out of close votes and got a low quality question that I couldn't do anything about.

Another solution might be to allow the casting of a "should be closed" suggestion just to drive down the questions score a little (i.e. counteracting "looks ok" votes) instead of showing the, unusable, option to close.

Comment: LQ post can be resolved by editing - so number of close votes available shouldn't matter.

Comment: @nhahtdh At least half the questions I've come across can't be helped by editing. Most of them just really are `off topic`, `exact duplicate` or `not a real question` and I don't see how editing them can help there?

Comment: Sorry, just woken up so didn't read the post carefully. I think your suggestion makes sense, but probably better implemented as reducing chance the next item being a question.

Comment: In LQ review for answers, running out of Delete votes results in fallback to Recommend Deletion [which is what reviewers <20K have]. Similarly, for LQ review of questions running out of Close Votes should change the button to Recommend Closure [which is what reviewers <3K have].

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii what about if a <3k user flagged it for close... and now can't flag it again?

Comment: @MichaelT Maybe it's the lack of coffee, but I can't connect your comment to mine. If I understand correctly, users who already acted on a post in certain ways are not eligible to review it; the precise conditions are complicated.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii its a tangent to the "Similarly, for LQ review of questions running out of Close Votes should change the button to Recommend Closure [which is what reviewers <3K have]" - but what if the <3k user already cast a flag on the question - what should it do then (as brought up in [Do not bring up posts in review that I myself flagged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276416/289086))?

Comment: @MichaelT Okay. My answer to that would be: tighten up eligibility check to exclude already-flagged posts. It's probably an oversight in the review design.

Answer (score 4):

You can pop a comment saying "This should be closed because..." and this will reach a larger audience of possible closers with enough close votes left. It will potentially reach people that are not so frequently visiting the low quality posts page, but just see your comment because they visit the question for another reason.